# Windows 10 sort folders with files

Tags: windows-10, sorting

In Windows 10 when I filter a folder by "Date modified" the folders and files are ordered independently. I have grouping set to none.

An example: If I have two files and a folder with the folder being the middle in terms of last modified it appears at the bottom. What I want is the folder placed in the appropriate spot - the middle.

How can I remove this assumption that Windows makes that I want my files and folders separately listed?

Comment: File Explorer (or Windows Explorer in earlier versions of Windows) has always sorted folders and files differently.  You would have to replace the shell to get different behavior. *This behavior can be seen all the way back to Windows 95.*

Comment: @Ramhound - Do you know how to configure explorer in Windows 10 with my desired behaviour?

Comment: You can't, which is the reason, I indicate you would have to use a different shell if you wanted files and folders to be sorted together instead of separately.

Comment: There is a trick where you can enter an asterisk "*" in the search box. It will then show the folders and files sorted together. BUT it will also sort the contents of all the folders together with it.