# Windows 10 on some computers will sort folders the same as files

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

How can I make Windows 10 keep the folders at the top/front of the list whenever I sort based on other criteria?

I have noticed that on some computers, in some circumstances, Windows 10 will sort files and folders with each other.  In some circumstances, the folders will appear *after* the files.  I **DO NOT WANT** this.  This is contrary to how Windows, and DOS, has done things for the past 25+ years, and yet another ***un***wanted change.

- This [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1323512/windows-10-sort-folders-with-files) and this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/329127/windows-7-any-way-to-sort-folders-and-files-all-mixed-together) are **THE OPPOSITE** of
  what I want to do
- This [article](https://www.howtogeek.com/67100/force-your-mac-to-put-folders-on-top-of-files-windows-style/) applies to a **different OS**, but is in effect what I would like to do
- This [question](https://superuser.com/questions/204016/windows-explorer-sorts-files-and-folders-separately) outlines the behavior that I want to restore, as behavior that they want to change (it's **not a duplicate**, it's a tangent inverted to what I want).
- This [forum post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-explorer-10-how-can-i-arrange-folders-on/4422fd25-ba5f-4024-8616-22f710f7bdaa) is the same as what I want to do.  However, it seems that there is no permanent solution based on their commentary and my own testing.

I am guessing I will need a registry edit to roll back the change, but so far I have been unsuccessful finding such a thing on [askvg](https://www.askvg.com/), [superuser](https://superuser.com/), [tenforums](https://www.tenforums.com/), [How To Geek](https://www.howtogeek.com/), or a [DDG](https://duckduckgo.com/) search.

**NOTE:** I have not determined the criteria when Windows does this.

**NOTE:** I use list view, not detail view.

[image]

*`The emphasis is to clearly make my point.  I find that netizens typically invert what I say for some strange reason, so I'm making it harder to misunderstand things backwards like that.  Such emphasis should not be necessary, yet here we are.`*

Answer (score 0):

1. Sort your folder as you desire
2. Shift-click on the "name" column.

Folders are now on top. Windows will "remember" this the next time you open that folder.

This will work as long as you don't sort descending by name (Z -> A), in that case the folders remain on the bottom.

Source: [From this thread discussion on microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-explorer-10-how-can-i-arrange-folders-on/4422fd25-ba5f-4024-8616-22f710f7bdaa)

Answer (score 0):

Full method:

- Use Details view
- Click on "Date Modified" column to sort by it
- Shift+Click on the "Name" column
- Switch to your final viewing mode (which I understand is List)
- In the View pane, click Options
- In the dialog, View tab, click "Apply to folders"
- If prompted, click Yes
- Click OK.